# Bootstrap image clogged up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

Earlier my tabs width were in pixels. I moved it to percentage so that it fits every screen. Now sliding bootstrap images have been blurred . I have attached the screen shot here. Images sliding arrows have been dislocated as well.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQypy.png)

```
ul 
{
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

li 
{
white-space: nowrap;
width: 20%;
float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited 
{
display: block;
width:100%;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #98bf21;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img
{
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Here is my bootstrap code.

```
<div class="container">
<div id="boots" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#boots" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#boots" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#boots" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>


<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img border="0" src="images/boo1.jpg" alt="sale1" width="300"    height="350">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img border="0"  src="images/boo.jpg" alt="sale2" width="300" height="350">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img border="0" src="images/boo3.jpg" alt="sale3" width="300" height="350">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Left and right controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#boots" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#boots" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
 </div>
 </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Looking at this real quick I'm pretty sure its the 50% you added on the .carousel-inner images. You may need to set the height: auto so the images dont become distorted.

Comment: @crazymatt No change after adding height. Thx for the input.